# Determining the existence of a permutation in S5 under certain condition

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can there exist some permutation $f$ in $S_5$ such that $f\cdot(1\,2\,3)\cdot(4\,5)=(1\,2\,3\,4\,5)\cdot f$?

Solution: Let us consider the element $4$ in the set $S=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ in the initial state. Under the action of $(1\,2\,3)\cdot(4\,5)$ it will turn into $5$ which will then be acted upon by $f$. Let us assume $f(5)=x$. Where as suppose $f(4)=y$. 
Now lets us consider the element $5$ in the initial state. Now $5$ will turn into $4$ by the action of $(1\,2\,3)\cdot(4\,5)$ and then $f$ will take it to $f(4)=y$. Where as $f$ will take $4$ to $x$ in the initial stage. Therefore, if $f$ has to be a consistent permutation then $(1\,2\,3\,4\,5)$ must have an independent transposition $(x,y)$ in it, but $(1\,2\,3\,4\,5)$ contains no such function. So $f$ does not exists.

Can you point out any better proof?

Comment: In response to a comment on my answer: Since the issue was about the question, not the answer, I respond here. I am not sure what part of the edit you object to. I think all that was done was to convert your math to LaTeX. I did correct one minor mishap from your latest edit.

Comment: Sorry that i am not yet very comfortable with the editing part. "Where as f will take 4 by action on X in the initial stage." this part should be " Where as f will take 4 to x (small x) in the initial stage." It will be preferable if you could change X= {12345} into S={12345}.

Comment: Okay, I did as you wish. But only this once! Editing isn't that hard, if you just don't mess too much with the latex code.

Comment: I would be really happy if I could do it myself, independently. Thank you very much. Sorry for disturbing you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $(123)\cdot(45)$ is an odd permutation, while $(12345)$ is even.

Comment: ok then no way the Sign of one side can be equal with the Sign of other side of the equation therefore F does not exists.

Comment: Yup, that's it.

Comment: I don't know why do I always get the more complex arguments than the much simple ones.

Comment: My question has been edited wrongly by some member. i am unable to rectify it. Please help me do it. I am new to this forum.

Comment: @SouravChakraborty: Are u interested to have a computational approach?